# Configuring youtube-dl

Tags: command-line, downloads, youtube

I want to configure `youtube-dl`, that it downloads only audio files in mp3. and in its help it shows the following line:

```
   You  can  configure  youtube-dl by placing default arguments (such as
   --extract-audio --no-mtime to always extract the audio and  not  copy
   the     mtime)     into     /etc/youtube-dl.conf    and/or    ~/.con‐
   fig/youtube-dl.conf."
```

BUT in my etc folder is no `youtube-dl.conf` file, nor is one in the `.config` folder (im a bloody greenhorn, took me 15 minutes to find the .config folder..)

can anyone help me to configurate youtube-dl?
btw.: I already made it to download the files in mp3 by manual command, but I need to type the commands after every download :/

I have ubuntu 13..... 10? I think? 13. something for sure =) thanks!

Comment: Why not make an alias command for downloading only audio files in mp3 format with youtube-dl, and call it whatever you want, for example *yt-mp3* ? Then you can use either youtube-dl or yt-mp3 depending on what you want to download.

Comment: What are the commands that you are using from the commandline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the config file yourself, it's not created by installation of the program.

Just save from your editor to  `~/.config/youtube-dl.conf` (note no dash in `.config`).

The system-wide default configuration file, `/etc/youtube-dl.conf`, could be created by installing, but is not. That's not a problem, as the file format is not complicated, so an example file is not important.

---

Not sure what exactly you are doing, but if it's about repeating the download command with a different url, try using the shell history, pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> to recall the command, and edit the file name.

(To show your Ubuntu version, use `lsb_release -a`)

Answer (score 0):

i made an "executable" for downloading musics from youtube ...
my ubuntu 14.10 also does not show up those config files, so what this does is basically executing the cmd for youtube-dl (instead of strange names it uses only what shows up on youtube, without the link in the end) , converts to mp3 and discards video.

to use this you need to:

> create a file: (terminal -> `touch download.sh`)
>
> paste this:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> #youtube to mp3 downloader
> youtube-dl -o '%(title)s.mp4' --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 $1
> mv *.mp3 ~/Music/
> ```
>
> terminal again: `chmod +x download.sh`
>
> to download simply do: sh download.sh link
>
> > ex: sh download.sh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trolololololol
>
> as it's now executable, you can also do `./download.sh link`, your choice ;)

Ps , i'm assuming the creation path as your home (`~/download.sh`), so when you open terminal, it's where you should be able to execute it ...

Cheers